# .net Report, with my LinkedListe<DatabaseData>

Tags: c#, reportviewer, windows-forms-designer, linked-list

I dont know if it is even possible.

But what i have allready is a Linkedlist filled with my own objects of class DatabaseData.
This list i would like to have availible to print in a certain format, and for this i would use a WFC, with reportviewer and then make a report for it.

But I have no idea how to get my LinkedList as datasource so i can arrange the data as i would like them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

answers it all, took along time to find it, but it is there